# Cannot communicate between containers using Rest API

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, rest, dockerfile

I have two simple endpoints:

On port 8080

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class LogonPageApplication {
private static final String PROCESS_STRING_URL = "http://localhost:8081/processString";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LogonPageApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/send")
    public String test() {
        String responseBody = "";
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpHeaders headers 
            = new HttpHeaders();headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            String requestBody = "{fromlogon}";
            HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);
    
            ResponseEntity<String> response =
            restTemplate.exchange(PROCESS_STRING_URL, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);
    
            responseBody = response.getBody();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
            return "Main Page\n" + "Response from /processString: " + responseBody;
        }

}
```

On port 8081:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class AcceptMessageApplication {

    public static void main(String\[\] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AcceptMessageApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String testt() {
        return "Accept-message-Page";
    }

    @PostMapping("/processString")
    public String processString(@RequestBody String inputString) {
        return "Processed string: " + inputString;
    }

}
```

I also have two Dockerfiles:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/LogonPage-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/LogonPageApplication.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "LogonPageApplication.jar"]
```

The only difference between them is jarfile name - one is logon and the other is AcceptMessage

So I am running my application using:

```
docker network create my_network
docker build -t logon-page-app .
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --network my_network --name logon-page-container logon-page-app
docker build -t accept-page-app .
docker run -d -p 8081:8080 --network my_network --name accept-page-container accept-page-app
```

While the app works just fine on running it from a console and sending a requst via Postman, I cannot get them to exchange message having dockerized it whenever I enter http://localhost:8080/send.

Comment: `localhost` is `localhost` inside the container. Create a docker compose file and make the URL configurable and then use the service name instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Are you calling `http://localhost:8080/send` from docker internal host or from you machine?

Comment: You should not use `localhost`, it works only within container, instead please investigate the ip address of your docker container you want to reach and use it. Otherwise but more harder - use variant that was proposed by M. Deinum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as people mentioned in comments it is not a java problem but networking with dockers problem.

I don't have an example with java project atm but this one should work as well .

So here you have docker-compose.yml file for setting up magento service

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  web:
    image: alexcheng/magento2
    ports:
      - "7082:80"
    links:
      - db
    volumes: 
      - magento-data:/var/www/html  
    environment:
      - MAGENTO_LANGUAGE=en_GB
      - MAGENTO_TIMEZONE=Pacific/Auckland
      - MAGENTO_DEFAULT_CURRENCY=NZD
      - MAGENTO_URL=http://local.magento
      - MAGENTO_BACKEND_FRONTNAME=admin
      - MAGENTO_USE_SECURE=0
      - MAGENTO_BASE_URL_SECURE=0
      - MAGENTO_USE_SECURE_ADMIN=0

      - MAGENTO_ADMIN_FIRSTNAME=Admin
      - MAGENTO_ADMIN_LASTNAME=MyStore
      - MAGENTO_ADMIN_EMAIL=amdin@example.com
      - MAGENTO_ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
      - MAGENTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6.23
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=myrootpassword
      - MYSQL_USER=magento
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=magento
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=magento
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8580:80"
    links:
      - db     
volumes:
  magento-data:
  db-data: %
```

As you can see there are 2 containers here, one named "web" which is magento itself, second one named "db" for database.

Now when I will run this docker-compose and will go to localhost:7082 I will see a configuration screen where I will need to put Database server host. If it wasn't a docker container I would put there "localhost" but since it is docker you need to put there name of the database container so "db" like here:

[image]

Btw. That docker-compose file if anyone want to run it was tested on mac os so I probably needs a bit of tweaks to run on other systems

you can run it just by using command

"sudo docker-compose up -d" or

"docker-compose up -d" depending on your OS

For clearing image use these commands:

sudo docker-compose down --remove-orphans

sudo docker volume rm $(sudo docker volume ls -q | grep magento)